# Display that a condition is true based on the joining of multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, subquery, where-clause

**Background:**

I would like to display all the people who have worked with the actor Ben Affleck.

**Here is my data:**

```
  People table
  
  id    name
 
  1     Ben Affleck
  2     Leonardio DiCaprio
  3     Matt Damon


  Movies table

  id   title
  1    Good Will Hunting
  2    example
  3    example


  Credits table
 
  id  movie_id person_id 
 
  1   1        1
  2   2        4
  3   3        6
```

**Desired Output**

```
 name         movie
 
 Matt Damon   Good Will Hunting
```

This is what I have tried:

I know that I must join the People, Movies, and Credits table together, as I am trying to find all the actors that have worked with Ben Affleck:

```
 SELECT p.name, m.title, c.movie_id
 FROM Credits c
 JOIN People p ON p.id = c.person_id
 JOIN Movies m ON m.id = p.id
 WHERE p.name = 'Ben Affleck';
```

I am still researching this.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Your overall goal is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use `IN`, which sometimes is less confusing to understand than `EXISTS`. You also had an error in joining `Movies` table in your initial query, you have to compare movie id from `Movies` which is `id` and movie id from `Credits` which is `movie_id`

```
SELECT p.name, m.title
FROM Credits c
JOIN People p ON p.id = c.person_id
JOIN Movies m ON m.id = c.movie_id
WHERE m.id IN (
  SELECT movie_id 
  FROM Credits c1
  JOIN People p1 on p1.id = c1.person_id
  WHERE p1.name = 'Ben Affleck'
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Both above worked well. I was getting confused with using the additional SELECT statement here.

Comment: In my version of query this additional SELECT is a so called "uncorrelated subquery", you can think about it as a completely separate query, it selects all movie ids, which starred `Ben Affleck`. The main query then takes all the people and their movies among the movies that we found in the subquery

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exists`:

```
select p.name, m.title, c.movie_id
from people p
inner join credits c on c.person_id = p.id
inner join movies m on m.id = c.movie_id
where exists (
    select 1 
    from people p1
    inner join credits c1 on c1.person_id = p1.id
    where c1.movie_id = c.movie_id and p1.name = 'Ben Affleck'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an IN clause, but you don't need Ben Affleck shown as well

```
 SELECT 
    p.name, m.title, c.movie_id
FROM
    Credits c
        JOIN
    People p ON p.id = c.person_id
        JOIN
    Movies m ON m.id = p.id
WHERE
    m.id IN (SELECT 
            movie_id
        FROM
            credis
        WHERE
            person_id IN (SELECT 
                    id
                FROM
                    People
                WHERE
                    name = 'Ben Affleck'))
    AND p.name <> 'Ben Affleck'
```